# TCP errors explain

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory

Could anyone explain these errors:

```
TCP ACKed unseen segment
TCP Dup ACK
TCP Previous segment not captured
TCP Out-Of-Order
TCP Retransmission
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that these are packet capture descriptions from Wireshark.

> **TCP ACKed unseen segment**
>
> Means that this packet acknowledges data that wasn't captured. It was
> transferred okay, and the receiver acknowledges it, but Wireshark
> can't find the packet in the capture. This usually happens when the
> capture device wasn't fast enough.

**TCP Dup ACK** answered [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38471/what-does-tcp-dup-ack-mean)

> **TCP Previous segment not captured**
>
> If packet N is marked with previous segment not captured, it means
> that in the capture there is no packet from the same TCP session whose
> seq + length would match the seq of packet N. The most typical reason
> is packet loss and/or late start of capture, which is the reason why
> the wording in question is used. But there can eventually be other
> reasons (buggy TCP stack of the sender, multipath network structure
> allowing packets belonging to the same TCP session to pass through
> different network interfaces so the packets do reach their destination
> but Wireshark cannot see them, ...), so it is up to you to check out
> the real reason why this has happened in your particular case.
>
> **TCP Out-Of-Order**
>
> It simply means that particular frame was received in a different
> order from which it was sent (after a later packet in the sequence).
> It is not generally a problem. It probably indicates there are
> multiple paths between source and destination - and one travels a
> through a longer path. It means TCP has slightly more work to
> reassemble segments in the correct order.
>
> **TCP Retransmission**
>
> When the receiving socket detects an incoming segment of data, it uses
> the acknowledgement number in the TCP header to indicate receipt.
> After sending a packet of data, the sender will start a retransmission
> timer of variable length. If it does not receive an acknowledgment
> before the timer expires, the sender will assume the segment has been
> lost and will retransmit it. The TCP retransmission mechanism ensures
> that data is reliably sent from end to end. If retransmissions are
> detected in a TCP connection, it is logical to assume that packet loss
> has occurred on the network somewhere between client and server.

You can find more useful info about wireshark [here](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/)

Comment: yes these are packet capture from wireshark. Thank you